# Best Java thread-safe locking mechanism for collections?

Tags: java, collections

What would be the least-slow thread-safe mechanism for controlling multiple accesses to a collection in Java?

I am adding objects to the top of a collection and i am very unsure what would be the best performing collection. Would it be a vector or a queue? I originally thought an ArrayList would be fast but i ran some experiments and it was very slow.

EDIT: In my insertion testing a Vector delared using volatile seems to be the fastest?

Comment: What *exactly* are the typical operations? Do you need random access? More reads than writes? Adding/removing elements to the beginning or end?

Comment: Adding to the end very regularly and removing everything but the first and last elements. No random insertions/deletions.

More writes than reads i would say.

Comment: Have a look at the [java.util.concurrent package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Shouldn't be too hard to find one. I like ConcurrentLinkedQueue and CopyOnWriteArrayList myself...

Comment: What kind of reads? (from the ends or from random places in the middle?)

Comment: Always from the end and/or beginning.

Comment: The size method of ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not run in constant time. Don't know if that matters to you.

Comment: When you say writes, do you mean `.set()` or `.add()`? If you're doing a lot of adding NOT at the end, I'd suggest a `LinkedList` wrapped in `Collections.synchronizedList()`. If you're doing a lot of setting, I'd suggest an `ArrayList` wrapped in the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact operations used should determine what is used. However, since the container is *largely* an abstract type, write it so it works -- reliably -- then profile, ensure functional requirements, optimize as needed, blah blah :)

Normally, my main use for a ["concurrent collection"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) is a Queue that is used to transfer objects between threads. In this case I start with [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) if for no other reason than liking the "lock-free" algorithm (this doesn't mean it will be faster though :-).

Generally a Queue and/or LinkedList is a good data-structure to append to the end. Depending upon the circumstances including *specific usage patterns including: thread contention, number of items removed, how items are removed, etc*, a "fast-kill" of all but the start/end *might* be accomplished faster with a `clear` (part of AbstractQueue) and item re-addition -- ConcurrentLinkedQueue allows both head *and* tail inspection/manipulation. However, I would urge "keeping it simpler", writing to a "specific interface contract" and "just use the current approach" until there is strong evidence that a functional-requirement is not met.

As far as the performance, it really depends upon the particular use-case/operations data-structure characteristics and data-structure implementation. ArrayList may very will be slower than Vector in some cases, and is indeed documented to be. If this performance makes the difference though, something sounds fishy. The article at [Java Best Practices – Vector vs ArrayList vs HashSet](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/08/java-best-practices-vector-arraylist.html) contains a nice read. Pay attention to the comments as well.

**Edit:** Remember that a "concurrent" data-structure generally only implies that a *single operation* (method call) is atomic (and perhaps not all operations in odd cases!). It may still be required to implement a large-scoped synchronization or other approach to achieve the required level of thread-safety. That is, a `h.putIfAbsent(k,v)` (from ConcurrentHashMap) is *not the same* as a `if (!h.containsKey(k)) { h.put(k, v); }` -- as a case-in-point, an issue like this applies to the "clear then add" approach mentioned above.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

See collections in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 5):

The best algorithms avoid shared state as much as possible. It sounds like you are new to multi threaded programming in java. Why not just pick something that you know will be correct.... Then see how much synchronisation there is, then see if that is a problem...then see if you can find a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps write your own implementation of a LinkedList?

The one in the java collection only holds a current pointer I believe. You can have one that holds head and tail...

You can also wrap it inside of a Collections.synchronizedList(...)

Comment: I'm getting confused because from my testing Vector appears to be the fastest easilly for just insertions? But i was under the impression it was synchronised and should be slower than some of the non-synchronised containers?

Comment: Vector is synchronized. And I believe that it uses something like System.arrayCopy(...) which is quite fast. However, with a custom implementation of LinkedList, you can just have the head and tail pointers changed to drop all but the first and last elements. This would be quite poor for random access though.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, if I understand comment "Vector using volatile" correctly, you may not quite understand what synchronization means. Volatile would only apply to reference to Vector; and since Vector itself is synchronized it would be redundant.

But fundamentally do you really think that performance differences due to synchronization (for container access) matter enough for you to worry? If you do, you should be able to see the effect with profiling (hot spots in access and/or mutation). I am not saying there aren't cases where this can occur, but they are not particularly common.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentSkipListMap/Set -- but you have to know how/WHEN to use it. CopyOnWriteArrayList is another wonderful solution (again need to know why you use it).

> > EDIT: In my insertion testing a Vector delared using volatile seems to be the fastest?

That's just uncool and totally not useful.