# multiple threads accessing an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

i have an ArrayList that's used to buffer data so that other threads can read them

this array constantly has data added to it since it's reading from a udp source, and the other threads constantly reading from that array.Then the data is removed from the array.

this is not the actual code but a simplified example :

```
 public class PacketReader implements Runnable{

   pubic static ArrayList<Packet> buffer = new ArrayList() ;
    @Override 
    public void run(){
    while(bActive){
    //read from udp source and add data to the array
  }
 }

 public class Player implements Runnable(){

 @Override 
 public void run(){


 //read packet from buffer
 //decode packets

 // now for the problem :

 PacketReader.buffer.remove(the packet that's been read);
     }
   }
```

The remove() method removes packets from the array and then shifts all the packets on the right to the left to cover the void.

My concern is : since the buffer is constantly being added to and read from by multiple threads , would the remove() method make issues since its gonna have to shift packets to the left?

i mean if .add() or .get() methods get called on that arraylist at the same time that shift is being done would it be a problem ?

i do get index out of bounds exception sometimes and its something like :
index : 100  size 300 , which is strange cuz index is within size , so i want to know if this is what may possibly be causing the problem or should i look for other problems .

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Java thread-safe locking mechanism for collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697371/best-java-thread-safe-locking-mechanism-for-collections)

Comment: Basically, yes, you'd expect to get `ConcurrentModificationException` out of this if you were using an Iterator.  Best to use something else entirely.

Comment: never had this error , thats what is confusing me ... i guess its not the problem ?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` is a symptom of multiple accesses to the structure that are sufficiently organized that they are detected by the implementation. For this sort of uncontrolled parallel access, I would expect wrong answers instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) is probably a good choice. If you need an unbounded queue and don't care about extra memory utilization (relative to `ArrayBlockingQueue`), [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) also works.

It lets you push items in and pop them out, in a thread-safe and efficient way. The behavior of those pushes and pops can differ (what happens when you try to push to a full queue, or pop from an empty one?), and the JavaDocs for the `BlockingQueue` interface have a table that shows all of these behaviors nicely.

---

A thread-safe `List` (regardless of whether it comes from `synchronizedList` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`) isn't actually enough, because your use case uses a classic check-then-act pattern, and that's inherently racy. Consider this snippet:

```
if(!list.isEmpty()) {
    Packet p = list.remove(0); // remove the first item
    process(p);
}
```

Even if `list` is thread-safe, this usage is not! What if `list` has one element during the "if" check, but then another thread removes it before you get to `remove(0)`?

You *can* get around this by synchronizing around both actions:

```
Pattern p;
synchronized (list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        p = null;
    } else {
        p = list.remove(0);
    }
}
if (p != null) {
    process(p);  // we don't want to call process(..) while still synchronized!
}
```

This is less efficient and takes more code than a `BlockingQueue`, though, so there's no reason to do it.

Comment: Agreed, from the question it sounds like this will be the best solution

Comment: replaced ArrayList with ArrayBlockingQueue , and add()/remove() with put() take() ... less cpu and memory usage , and no crashes :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there would be problems because ArrayList is not thread-safe, the internal state of the ArrayList object would be corrupted and eventually you would have some incorrect output or runtime exceptions appearing. You can try using [synchronizedList(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-), or if it's a good fit you could try using a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

This issue is the [Producer–consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). You can see how much people fix it by using a lock of some kind taking turns extracting an object out of a buffer (a List in your case). There are thread safe buffer implementations you could look at as well if you don't necessarily need a List.