# Runtime errors when attempting to delete and shift array of object in GUI interface

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

My project consists of 2 class files and a test application GUI interface to use the data. The two class files, both created by me, are `ToolItem` (defines a hardware tool with `get()` and `set()` methods, `display()` method, etc) and `HardWareStore`, which is used to manipulate the data and place it into an array using methods like `insert()`, `delete()`, `searchArray()` ect.

The GUI interface, which includes the same relative buttons (insert, delete) calls `HardWareStore` when the corresponding button is pressed.

So far everything works perfectly EXCEPT the delete button/`delete()` method. My methods are as follows, including the `searchArray()` method I created which is used inside `delete()` to evaluate a unique ID and determine if the ID already exists or not:

searchArray:

```
public int searchArray(int id)
    {
        for (index = 0; index < toolArray.length; index++)
        {
            if (toolArray[index].getToolID() == id)
            {
                System.out.println("ID found at location " + index);
                return index;
            }
        }   
        return -1;
    }//end searchArray
```

delete:

```
public int delete(int ID)
    {
        testArray = searchArray(ID);   

        if (testArray != -1)
        {   
            toolArray[testArray].setQuality(0);
            toolArray[testArray].setToolName("");
            toolArray[testArray].setID(0);
            toolArray[testArray].setNumberInStock(0);
            toolArray[testArray].setPrice(0.0);

            //counter for number of items in array. Array holds 10 objects
            numberOfItems--; 

            //shifting cells
            for (index = testArray + 1; index < toolArray.length; index++)
            {
                toolArray[index - 1] = toolArray[index];
            }

            toolArray[toolArray.length - 1] = null;

            System.out.println("Successful deletion");
            return 1;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("ID not found");
            return -1;

    }//end delete
```

And here is the corresponding GUI button used to delete the data in my test application:

```
else if (ev.getSource() == deleteBtn)
            {
                input = idFld.getText();
                idInput = Integer.parseInt(input);

                responseCode = store.delete(idInput);

                if (responseCode == 1)
                {
                    messageFld.setText(idInput + " - Successful deletion");
                }
                else if (responseCode == -1)
                {
                    messageFld.setText(idInput + " - ID not found");
                }

            }//end delete button
```

Now, everything inserts fine, detects duplicate ID's, and so on. The delete method also works, letting me know that the user passed ID has been deleted at toolArray[index] as well as all of it's related data members.

The error occurs when I go to display the items in the array. The first 9 items display fine using JOptionPane, but when I reach item 10(my delete method is supposed to shift all cells to the left after deletion) I get several runtime errors starting with:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I'm pretty sure my error starts with the `delete()` method in `HardWareStore`, specifically my loop to delete and shift the items to left. I've messed with it for a few hours but I cannot seem to find why, and my attempts to change the loop either result in another runtime error, or the method doesn't behave like it should.

Comment: does the delete() and reading from the array "get()" happen at same time ? say on different threads for example ?

Comment: I looked thru the exception list and it didn't appear so. I didn't see a reference to any of the get() methods in the runtime errors, but i'm not 100% sure :/ The first exceptions were at searchArray() and insert() which, ironically enough, and the methods that work fine under normal circumstances. It's only when I delete an item and attempt to insert() another object or display() said data do the runtime errors occur. This is why I think it's an issue with the way i'm shifting the array.

Comment: i dint mean get() precicely , i meant any kind of access to the array simultaneous to the deleting , cuz if u delete thus shift and read at the same time , the data will be corrupted , had this problem before...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917931/multiple-threads-accessing-an-arraylist

Comment: Oh alright. Well if anything I learned something. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one general remark, and that's not to use Java primitive Arrays. Save yourself a lot of trouble and use [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). That way you can simply [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) an element at an index, there's no need then to manually manage elements in a primitive array.

Without a clear exception trace and a code snippet that shows how things are displayed I'm just speculating, but when you delete an item you shift everything manually and append a `null` value at the end of the array. When your array is then displayed you are most likely hitting a `NullPointerException` when dereferencing a `null` object.

In general you should only rarely have the need for primitive arrays. Use an `ArrayList` instead and delete items using its `remove` method.